# How to drop and re-create a view on all DB's on a server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently had a need to drop and recreate a view across all DB's on a server. Our original script used a cursor which we found to be a bit inefficient. In an earlier qution that I asked on here, the sys.sp_MSforeachdb prcedure was brought to my attention. I was able to use it to do exactly what was needed.

You just have to be mindful of the length of the exec statement. Apparently there is a length limit, the exact scripts I had were throwing errors until I removed all the aliases and bunched up the select statement. I had about 80 columns in it on separate lines.There were some aliases that were necessary, so I obviously left those where needed.

Comment: I have an answer to post once I format it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I ended up with:

```
USE [Master]

EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
'USE [?]; IF db_name() NOT IN  (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''ReportServer'',''ReportServerTempDB'',''tempdb'')
BEGIN USE ?

    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[ViewName]''))
        DROP VIEW [ViewName]

    EXEC(''
            CREATE VIEW ViewName AS

            SELECT
            db_name() DBName, a.Col1,a.Col2,a.Col3,t.Col1

            FROM Activity a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TerminologyCache t ON a.ActivityTypeName = t.TerminologyKeyName
            WHERE
            a.activityProviderName = ''''Parm1''''
            and (ISNULL(t.TerminologyCultureName,''''en-US'''') = ''''en-US'''')

        '')

END'
```

Comment: Why not encapsulate this method inside a executesql method? Seems a bit risky to be running this so nakedly across all your DB's.